# How to get the value that I entered in the textbox when click the button?

Tags: node.js, angular

**.HTML**

```
<input type="email" #inputvalue>
<button type="submit" (submit)="onSubmit(inputvalue.value)">Verify</button>
```

**.TS**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   inputvalue: any;

   onSubmit(inputvalue: any) {
   this.inputvalue = inputvalue;
   console.log(this.inputvalue)
  }
}
```

- I want to get the values that I entered in textbox to **inputvalue** variable after click the verify button.

Comment: Why don't you use `ngModel`?

Comment: Can you give me update according to my code. Because i knew to angular.

Comment: Please read through the angular docs first if you are new, `ngModel` is the first thing to learn about angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anurag has mentioned in his comment you should go and learn a bit about [Angular](https://angular.io/start).
There are two ways you can achieve this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="email" [(ngModel)]="emailValue">
<input type="email" #email>
<button (click)="submit()">Verify</button>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  emailValue: string;
  @ViewChild('email', {static: true}) email: ElementRef;

  submit() {
   console.log(this.emailValue)
   console.log(this.email.nativeElement.value)
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjgmj6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: email: ElementRef; In here 'email' showing as error and result is undifined & show ƒ Error() { [native code] }

Comment: I've added the Stackblitz link to the answer, there are no errors.

Comment: Its fixed now & work thank you so much! And I have a question why use "nativelemnt" keyword why can't use only "this.emailvalue". What is the reason?

Comment: You can use either. I've just shown you two different ways of achieving the same thing. There are more ways like using `[fromControl]` or `formControlName` inside a `form` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Also instead of ngModel TWO way binding you can use  **formControlName = "emailValue"**, You just need a parent FormGroup in html. You can read about using FormGroup online. It is better and maintainable as compared to ngModel